# How to detect SwiftUI DatePicker date selection dismissal?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, datepicker

I am looking for a way to detect, when a user touches outside DatePicker when selecting a date and with this makes the date picker to close.

```
@State private var date = Date()
@State private var isOpened = false

public init() {
    self.date = Date()
    self.isOpened = false
}

//ozadje barva
public var body: some View {
    HStack() {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text("Start date")
            Text(date.toString("dd-mm-yyy"))
        }
        Image(isOpened ? .icnClose : .icnCalendar)
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(
                width: 24,
                height: 24,
                alignment: .center
            )
    }.overlay {
        DatePicker(
            "",
            selection: $date,
            displayedComponents: [.date])
        .datePickerStyle(.compact)
        .labelsHidden()
        .blendMode(.destinationOver)
        .onTapGesture(perform: {
            print("tapped")
        })
    }
}
```

I would need this to change the look of the view. I can detect when the user clicks again inside DatePicker with tapGesture, but not when he clicks outside.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

EDIT 1:
The preferred solution would be, to somehow detect the dismissal from this component, so I don't have to do anything additional on the view where I will be placing this component.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place an `onTapGesture` on the most external container like this to do so:

```
VStack {
    /// Your DatePicker and other Views here
}
/// Add these lines here
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
/// Use this to make the View detect a tap, otherwise it will only work if the view has some solid color
.contentShape(.rect)
.onTapGesture {
    print("Tap Outside")
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: It probably would, but not for how I had in mind, I was thinking more of something on this view/component, so that I don't need additional code/variables from superview

Comment: I can't think of any other way about how to detect a tap outside without involving other variables such as the ones used to present sheets for example, and/or more code.